# Error message "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" while appending imgs into divs using javascript createElement()

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dynamic, appendchild

New to js here. I want to append each image tag (15 of them) into its own div tag. However, I ran into a "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" error in the console.

```
function createImage()
{
    const DIV_ID = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'b10', 'b11', 'b12',
    'b13', 'b14', 'b15'];

    img = [];
    container = [];

    width = 120;
    height = 120;

    var src = "rdmImg.png";
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        container[i] = document.createElement('div');
        container[i].setAttribute = ("id", `${DIV_ID[i]}`);
        document.body.appendChild(container[i]);

        img[i] = document.createElement('img'); 
        img[i].src = src;
        img[i].width = width;
        img[i].height = height;
        document.getElementById(`${DIV_ID[i]}`).appendChild(img[i]); //Cannot read property of null
    }
```

Any hand is very much appreciated!

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `.setAttribute("id", \`${DIV_ID[i]}\`); `

Comment: `container[i].setAttribute = ("id", `${DIV_ID[i]}`);` you have `=` but it should just be `container[i].setAttribute("id", `${DIV_ID[i]}`);